# Significant CPU usage after denying ip in IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

I have been restricting IP addresses that are responsible for high bandwidth and hits (determined to belong to companies scraping data from our site).  As soon as I add a ip in deny mode to the list the server's cpu usage hits 100% for a good 10 seconds or so.  Is this supposed to happen when you deny an IP in iis7?  (Is the CPU usage caused by the under-the-hood process involved in denying an ip?)

And another question - is there any scenario in which blocking an IP using this method could actually hurt server performance?  (replacing a situation where the host requests, downloads data, and repeats  with a situation where the ip requests, is denied, and immediaty keeps trying.. much faster than before it was blocked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to block those IP addresses before they even reach IIS. Use IPSec Security Policy, firewall, etc.

Comment: I might just do that.   Is there a way to get the list from IIS into a text file?  (I'll google it but no harm in asking)

Comment: I found a way.  A powershell script that does it quite nicely - http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Export-IP-Address-and-a65d81d5